# Change built-in default privileges in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, permissions

## Introduction.

When I create a database,

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE test2 OWNER test2;
```

it is created with an **empty** privileges column:

```
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 test2     | test2    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

Now, it is important to note that this is not the same situation as it having no privileges granted whatsoever. In the latter case, the column contains just `{}` (which by the way displays as empty, too, in `postgres=# \l`, *AFAIR*).

- An empty field means that PostgreSQL uses built-in default privileges.
- `{}` means that there are literally no privileges to the database.

## Research.

In our case, these built-in defaults happen to be:

```
=Tc/test2  +  test2=CTc/test2
```

How do I know that? I issued:

```
postgres=# GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test2 TO test1;
```

... and that resulted in:

```
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 test2     | test2    | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/test2            +
           |          |          |             |             | test2=CTc/test2      +
           |          |          |             |             | test1=c/test2
```

... that is the implicit defaults plus `test1=c/test2` granted explicitly.

## Problem & question.

While I have no problem with `=CTc` granted to `owner` in these defaults, I'd like not to have `=Tc` granted to `PUBLIC`.

Sure, I can just `REVOKE ALL [...] FROM PUBLIC` after creation, but is there a way to automatize it?

## Afterthought.

Really, why aren't these defaults as I want them by default? Is it a popular practice to run one PostgreSQL server for one app, not just one database on the server per app, even if it is a small one?

E.g. default installation of phpPgAdmin "crashes" when it stumbles upon a database it has no connect privs, I had to modify the source a bit. And despite numerous bug reports, it's been doing so for at least six months now (I can't remember any date of the reports, but one of them stated that six months had passed).

Comment: I think that everything in new database (including rights) is inherited from database template1.

Comment: @pavel242, see **dezso** answer below, to see that's not true... Unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported in PostgreSQL out of the box.  Perhaps you should send in a feature request (or a patch).

Answer (score 4):

The `CONNECT` privilege for `PUBLIC` looks somewhat special:

```
\l
template1   | postgres | UTF8     | Hungarian, Hungary | Hungarian, Hungary | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

That is, user `test` (which is the member of `PUBLIC` only) cannot connect to `template1`:

```
postgres=# \c template1 test
Password for user test:
FATAL:  permission denied for database "template1"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
Previous connection kept
```

Now let's create a database on top of this:

```
CREATE DATABASE test3 TEMPLATE template1;
```

And connect to it with test:

```
postgres=# \c test3 test
Password for user test:
You are now connected to database "test3" as user "test".
test3=> \c postgres postgres
```

Just a bit of context:

```
postgres=# SELECT version();
                           version
-------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit
(1 row)
```

With this in mind and the fact that `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` does not provide means the change the defaults on the database level, I would say there is no way to do this automatically.  If you have to create lots of databases, probably a setup script would come handy.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly the behavior I want to avoid. I'd like your user `test` not to be able to connect to **any** newly created database, including your `test3`.

Comment: @MichałRus Please see my edit above.

Comment: +1 for this check. :) Well. I've just posted to [pgsql-admin](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAH=q+8LtTyiX3yD3ysKWcU-aqCrOo0Y_EYB7F7Jm_Ew7Zhi4+Q@mail.gmail.com), perhaps they'll tell us.

Comment: (Obviously, I'll be happy to accept your answer if it is really impossible to do so, let's wait for the "official" statement).

Comment: @MichałRus the official answer arrived from Peter.